# Xcode UITableView change programmatically created cell text color on highlight

Tags: xcode, uitableview, selection, tableview

I have added some text to a UITableViewCell by creating the label with the correct coords, then typing the following:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelDesc];
```

All is well. I had an issue with the labels "duplicating" and overlapping, but I fixed it by putting the code in the `if (cell == nil)` function.
Now my question is: When you select the cell it highlights in blue. With the default `cell.textLabel.text` it goes white when highlighted. This does not happen on my custom labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you select the cell it highlights in blue. With the default
>   cell.textLabel.text it goes white when highlighted. This does not
>   happen on my custom labels. Could someone explain how to do this
>   please?

`UILabel` has a property named [highlightedTextColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/highlightedTextColor). You need to set this property:

```
labelDesc.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: @albertamg I just cant thank you enough. I have been going mad for two days. thanks lot.

Comment: @albertamg Wow, my apologies for the ~5 year delay! ;) accepted as answer.